# Issue with show all users in the table with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, html-table

I have the next issue, when I need the code show me all the users in the table always show me one data the first one or the last one if I change the ASC to DESC inside of SELECT..
I need to show me all users... can you please help me with this?

Here the code and the table with the row I need to show:

```
<?
include '../include/config.php';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM PACIENTES ORDER BY id_paciente ASC';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

        $id_paciente = $row['id_paciente'];
        $id_tipo = $row['id_tipo'];
        $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $apellido = $row['apellido'];
        $ciudad = $row['ciudad'];
        $telefono = $row['telefono'];
        $foto = $row['foto'];
}       
?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $id_paciente; ?></th>
            <td><img src="../<?php echo $foto;?>" class="image_thumbnail" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $nombre; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $apellido; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $id_tipo; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ciudad; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $telefono; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I get my answer with my problem...

now I see all the users, the code neccesary is:

```
<?
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM PACIENTES ORDER BY id_paciente ASC';
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
```

for somebody want to

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing your variables *outside* of the loop.
So, move it inside:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM PACIENTES ORDER BY id_paciente ASC';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['id_paciente'] ?></th>
        <td><img src="../<?php echo $row['foto']?>" class="image_thumbnail" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['apellido'] ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['id_tipo'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ciudad'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefono'] ?></td>
    <tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: not work always show me one user, I already have in this demo db five users and just show me one...